# Ehcache возвращает null

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

element = new Element(StringId, 
cache.put(element);

Если попытаться извлечь элемент из кеша, то вернется null.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте MCVE https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve и подробнее опишите проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быстрофикс - это увеличить допустимое кол-во кэшируемых элементов.